# How to use mPDF with PHP 7.0.4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

How to use mPDF with latest version of PHP ( Codeigniter 3.x)?

I am using PHP 7.0.4 and codeigniter 3.x.  I include the mPDF in my project but getting following error

> Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; mPDF has a deprecated constructor

I tried by replacing function name with `__construct` but it is not working.
Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: you can change  as per this github link : https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/commit/61b0048530f1963c0913a548465e41a597d2908e

Comment: Thnx, its working. But My view file is Unicode ( Bangla ) when i convert it cant show my bangla font . any idea ???

Comment: you can set inline CSS for font.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your mpdf by mPDF 5.7 library for PHP7

Answer (score 0):

You can try development version of mPDF which can be obtained on GitHub or via composer with

```
$ composer require mpdf/mpdf@dev-development
```

You will have to set your `minimum-stability` accordingly.

There are some backwards incompatible changes - mainly namespaces and different constructor parameters.

WIP documentation can be read on GitHub at https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.github.io/blob/development/configuration/configuration-v7-x.md